# Ubuntu 16.04 - USB ports not working

Tags: 16.04, usb

I'm pretty much new to Ubuntu/Linux, so I'll need help step by step.

I've got two USB ports at the front and four at the back, just one at the back is working. All of them were working before, then just two at the back, then all again, and now just one at the back.

I've tried to look on other forums but I couldn't find any solution.

Don't know where to start :(

Comment: You need to consider hardware failure. In order to rule that out you can try booting a live session.

Comment: I'll have to try tomorrow as I don't have any stick memory in the office.

So, I'll get an usb stick with ubuntu and try to restart from it, that way I'll find if the ports are physically working, right?

Comment: Exactly. If you're sure the stick is properly made and boots in similar PCs but not in yours that settles the issue. If it still boots but other USB ports do not work in the live session that's also definitive. Also worth checking BIKOS/UEFI settings, something may have changed.

Comment: The type of ports can be a factor. Is the working port USB 2 and the non working USB 3? Does the working port have a lightning bolt symbol?

Comment: Ok, so I just try booting a live session on all usb ports, only two of them at the back working. 
What could be the fault for the rest not to be working?

Comment: By the way, the computer it's a bit old, so I think none of the ports will be USB 3.